# Using VBA to calculate unique random numbers in "i" number of rows

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I am currently working on a pet project of mine. I am currently making a combat calculator for a gaming group I DM. Essentially, I have a table with the monsters and their stats, and a cell with the number of monsters I want to include. When I press the command button, I want the table to populate with "i" number of monsters, and roll initiative, attack and damage for each one.

This is what I have so far

```
    Sub Fill()
    'Monster
        Dim i As Integer
        i = Range("W2").Value

        With Range("L2")
            .Value = ComboBox1.Value
            .AutoFill .Resize(i + 0, 1), xlFillCopy
        End With

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim Roll(1 To 8) As Variant
    Roll(1) = Int((10 - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1) + Range("E2").Value 'Initiative
    Roll(2) = Int((20 - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1) - Range("F2").Value 'Attack
    Roll(3) = Int(((Range("G2").Value) - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1) + Range("H2").Value 'Damage

    Roll(7) = Range("B2").Value
    Roll(4) = Range("D2").Value
    Roll(5) = Range("I2").Value
    Roll(6) = Range("J2").Value
    Roll(8) = Range("C2").Value


    LRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 12).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("M2:M" & LRow).Formula = Roll(1)
    .Range("N2:N" & LRow).Formula = Roll(2)
    .Range("O2:O" & LRow).Formula = Roll(3)
    .Range("P2:P" & LRow).Formula = Roll(4)
    .Range("Q2:Q" & LRow).Formula = Roll(5)
    .Range("R2:R" & LRow).Formula = Roll(6)
    .Range("S2:S" & LRow).Formula = Roll(7)
    .Range("T2:T" & LRow).Formula = Roll(8)
    End With


    End Sub
```

I am having trouble figuring out the proper command for calculating each subsequent monster's rolls. I end up rolling everything on row 2 (monster 1), and then monsters 2-10 are just copied, not rolled.

Comment: Is this all you want? If so there are TONS of apps out there which do this already. Here is an online encounter builder: http://www.kassoon.com/dnd/encounter-builder/ or http://www.asmor.com/scripts/4eEncounterGen/

Comment: I am still playing 2nd edition. Most of what I have found online is for 3+, and what I have found for AD&D is a bit clunky. I saw no harm in making something that suited my preferences exactly.

Comment: Your VBA is doing exactly what you've told it to do, take each roll and assign it to every populated row in a specific column. What are you trying to do? Re-roll for different monsters on each row?

Comment: Yeah, each row would be a different monster. I have "i" linked to a spin button. If I select 5 goblins, I have 5 rows populate, but the rolls are not unique for each monster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to re-roll for each monster (row) like this:

```
Sub Fill()

 Dim Roll(1 To 8) As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    i = Range("A3").End(xlDown).Row

    For j = 3 To i
    Roll(1) = Int((10 - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1) + Range("E2").Value 'Initiative
    Roll(2) = Int((20 - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1) - Range("F2").Value 'Attack
    Roll(3) = Int(((Range("G2").Value) - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1) + Range("H2").Value 'Damage

    Roll(7) = Range("B2").Value
    Roll(4) = Range("D2").Value
    Roll(5) = Range("I2").Value
    Roll(6) = Range("J2").Value
    Roll(8) = Range("C2").Value
        Cells(j, 2) = Roll(1)
        Cells(j, 3) = Roll(2)
        Cells(j, 4) = Roll(3)
        Cells(j, 5) = Roll(4)
        Cells(j, 6) = Roll(5)
        Cells(j, 7) = Roll(6)
        Cells(j, 8) = Roll(7)
    Next
End Sub
```

So for each row, it fills the array and then assigns it to each column as you define.

Comment: You are defining i to be the row that is being calculated, and j as the column. Why don't you have to define j as an integer too?

 Does that mean that your "For" statement is covering column 3 to whatever row you are on -2? The way you have it set up looks like You are applying the roll formulas to rows, not columns. For instance, everything in in column one needs to be rolled with Roll(1).

Am I just confused?

Comment: The `for` covers the integers yes. The format `cells(row, col)` is being used, so it's applying to columns. For instance roll(1) is always in column B. The `-2` isn't needed, you're right.